# Removing Evolution password under KDE?

Tags: kde, password, evolution

I'm using Evolution mail client under KDE. I want to get rid of entering my password each time I use it. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Evolution keeps it's passwords in gnome-keyring

Applications > Accessories > Passwords and Encryption Keys

From here, goto the passwords tab, find the correct password entry, double click on it, expand the password section, then click "show password" and change your password here.

Enter the old password (the one you've been prompted for when you start Evolution), but leave the new password fields blank.
It will prompt you with: Store Passwords Unencrypted?. Click on Use Unsafe Storage.

Log-out / Log-in